# Google account login problem in local host refine dev

Tags: localhost, google-signin, account

[Log in option to continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymfr3.png)
[Not showing any account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUHX.png)

Whenever I am trying to start my run dev command .. in local host it is asking for google account login, but when I choose to login .. the prompt does not show me any of my google account to continue with...
I am working on a REFINE project...

I tried to refresh it many times... and even change my browsers... still facing the same problem. I am already logged in with my g-mail account in that browser but still it is not showing my account to continue with my REFINE application setup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten to provide your 'clientId' value. Could you please check your 'clientId' value at https://github.com/refinedev/refine/blob/next/examples/auth-google-login/src/pages/login.tsx#L5?

Comment: I got the point but if you can elaborate a little how to find my clientId it would be really helpful.